# Ember Transform why use Ember.create() within deserialize return statement

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The Ember docs explain the Transform functionality with an example. I have a problem to understand one thing.

Question:

Why they use Ember.create() within deserialize function instead only the pure object?

Like return { x: value[0], y: value[1] } instead Ember.create({ x: value[0], y: value[1] }).

What are the benefits to use Ember.create() (especially in the Transform function)?

```
App.CoordinatePointTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  serialize: function(value) {
    return [value.get('x'), value.get('y')];
  },
  deserialize: function(value) {
    return Ember.create({ x: value[0], y: value[1] });
  }
});
App.Cursor = DS.Model.extend({
  position: DS.attr('coordinatePoint')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new instances with those properties (essentially a different copy).  In this case it's doing nothing of consequence and could just be the hash.

> Identical to Object.create(). Implements if not available natively.

http://emberjs.com/api/#method_create